# django parent child summation in view and pass to a template

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and would like to do the following i have a simple project and have a parent and child model of a Project and related Project Tasks. One Project will have multiple ProjectTasks. 
I want to be able to display the Project and ProjectTask sum through a template.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    projectContact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    projectTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    projectAddress1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    projectValueProposed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    projectValueActual = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectTitle

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    projectName = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    projectTaskDesc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    projectTaskContact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    projectTaskAmount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.projectTaskDesc
```

My view is as follows.

```
def index(request):
    project_list = Project.objects.all()
    project_task = ProjectTask.objects.all()
    ##project_task = ProjectTask.objects.all() ##filter(projectName=2).aggregate(amount=Sum('projectTaskAmount'))
    for pid in project_list:
        ptask = project_task.filter(projectName=pid.id)
    context = {'project_list':project_list,'project_task':ptask}
    return render(request,'construction/index.html',context)
```

and template is

```
{% if project_list %}
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Project name</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Customer</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Proposed Value</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Actual Value</th>
  </tr>

 {% for projects in project_list %}
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="{% url 'construction:projectview' projects.id%}">{{ projects.projectTitle }}</a></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ projects.projectContact }}</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ projects.projectValueProposed }}xx{{projects.id }}</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ project_task}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
 {% else %}
    <p>No projects are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I am using Admin to create Project and add projectTask which works well. 
I have two options:
1. To update the value of projectValueActual in the Project when i save the Admin page
2. To display dynamically the Project and sum of related ProjectTaskAmount

Need some help on how to prepare the values in the view (if that is the correct place to do it) and pass the context in some way i can display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the model properties can be made much less verbose. Also, adding a related_name to the ForeignKey, so you can directly reference it from the Project model.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    valueProposed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    valueActual = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='tasks')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

That makes the view much simpler

```
def index(request):
    ctx = {'project_list': Project.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'construction/index.html', ctx)
```

I am not quite sure what you want to do in your template, but lets assume you want to list all Tasks under each related Projects and then print the sum of the `ProjectTask.amount` values.

```
{% if project_list %}
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Project name</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Customer</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Proposed Value</th>
    <th class="tg-le8v">Actual Value</th>
  </tr>

  {% for project in project_list %}
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><a href="{% url 'construction:projectview' projects.id%}">{{ project.title }}</a></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ project.contact }}</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">{{ project.valueProposed }}xx{{projects.id }}</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      {% for task in project.tasks %}
        <span>{{ task.amount }}</span>
        {% if forloop.last %} = {% else %} + {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {{ project.sumTaskAmounts }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
 {% else %}
    <p>No projects are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And finally, to easily get the sum of all the `Task.amount` properties, you need to add a `@property` to `Project` that returns the sum of the `amount` values for each project's `ProjectTask` instances.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def sumTaskAmounts(self):
        return self.tasks.aggregate(amount=Sum('amount')).amount
```

Didn't test any of it, but that should more or less do it.

Comment: perfect solution. only change i did was to remove the .amount in models (was throwing an error) and use .amount in template. Now wondering how i could update the value in the Project.valueActual when i save the Admin form.'code'

Answer (score 0):

I've made the following changes to implement updating when i save the admin form.

models.py

```
  def update_total_amount(self):
        total=0
        total=self.task.aggregate(amount=Sum('amount'))
        self.valueActual=total['amount']
        self.save()
```

and in admin.py

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                instance.save()
            formset.save_m2m()
            instance.project.update_total_amount()
```

works for what I wanted to do. thanks for the help.